# Spring Boot Restful throwing unauthorised when it should throw HttpMethodNotSupported

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a Spring Boot application with Spring Security applied in it. It is throwing 401-Unauthorised when I call a GET API with POST method.

I have used a custom authentication filter which extends `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`.

I have given `http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint);` in my security config. If I comment this out, it gives me 403-Forbidden.

Can someone help with this, it should throw method not supported error. Is there any global configuration which I need to apply?

Comment: Maybe your `authenticationEntryPoint` throws 401 exception before execution reaches a point where `HttpMethodNotSupported` should be thrown.

Comment: If I remove "http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint);", it throws forbidden 403. Not sure what's happening here.

Comment: Could you make a minimal proof-of-concept project on Github ?